# DVB-T PCI cards not working since 23.04 upgrade

Tags: 23.04, dvb, dvb-t

Before an upgrade to Ubuntu 23.04 I had two PCI DVB-T cards that *worked perfectly*.

After the upgrade, there is no `/dev/dvb` directory, no DVB modules are loaded, and `dmesg` does not even mention the presence of the cards.

The correct firmware files have been been copied into `/lib/firmware/` - but even if they hadn't, I'd still expect to see the warning message in `dmesg`.

How do I go about diagnosing this?

```
# lspci -vv

04:00.0 Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7146 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: KNC One SAA7146
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32 (3750ns min, 9500ns max)
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 14
    Region 0: Memory at df201000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]

04:01.0 Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7146 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Technotrend Systemtechnik GmbH Technotrend-Budget/Hauppauge WinTV-NOVA-T DVB card
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32 (3750ns min, 9500ns max)
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 15
    Region 0: Memory at df200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
```

```
# dmesg | grep -i dvb
(no output)
```

```
# lsmod | grep -i dvb
(no ouptut)
```

EDIT:

```
# lspci -nnk -d "1131:*"
04:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Philips Semiconductors SAA7146 [1131:7146] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: KNC One SAA7146 [1894:003a]
04:01.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Philips Semiconductors SAA7146 [1131:7146] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Technotrend Systemtechnik GmbH Technotrend-Budget/Hauppauge WinTV-NOVA-T DVB card [13c2:1011]
```

```
# uname -a
Linux mediabox 6.2.0-24-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jun 16 12:03:50 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Everything I've read says I don't need to "fix" the udev rules.  But how can I check they're correct?  One used to make a new udev rule in the *olden days*.

Comment: I assume, without the used kernel version it will be hard to help. Please add the kernel and version to the question.

Comment: Please add the output of the command `lspci -nnk -d "1131:*"` to the question. I assume "1131" is the pci vendor id for the card. If not use the correct vendor id.

Comment: @Marco - I added that information.  Is there anything else needed?

Comment: At least, we see now, that there is no kernel module loaded for the devices. There should be something like "Kernel driver in use:" in the output. Do you know which kernel module is needed for the card?

Comment: @Marco - From memory `tt_budget` (?)    This pulls in `dvb_code`, etc.  I can't remember what the non-Hauppauge card uses.

Comment: I guess its "budget.ko". This module is not found in kernel 6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled it for you ...

In 2022 the driver for Saa7146 was moved to "deprecated" in Linux Kernel.

https://lore.kernel.org/linux-media/517fcea8-bc76-255c-da59-43c0b7f56486@xs4all.nl/

> The remaining patches move other non-vb2 drivers to this deprecated
> directory: cpia2, meye, zr364xx, tm6000, fsl-viu, some davinci
> drivers, and saa7146. Finally the deprecated staging driver av7110 is
> moved to deprecated/**saa7146**.
>
> Note that the ttpci (using just the DVB part of saa7146) was
> deprecated as well. It should be possible to extract it from the
> saa7146 driver as a DVB-only driver, but I am not certain if that is
> worth the effort.
>
> It's really very old hardware... (20+ years).

Last Kernel version containing Saa7146 driver was 5.19.